# Firebase database retrieve data with key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve my data but there are unique key on data parent like this https://photos.app.goo.gl/sowxnnJpMgUY6geo9

I want to set it to the spinner list. How can I possibly read the `tujuan` value only? For example, I want the value `Sebut Harga` and `Pegawai`. I don't want it read like this https://photos.app.goo.gl/7KCCUbARTZnVQvoM8 .

```
public void retrieveData(){
    listener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            spinnerDataList.clear();
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                keys.add(item.getKey());
                spinnerDataList.add(item.getValue().toString());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So you want to exclude an item ("SILA PILIH") from the results?

Comment: No, please refer the screenshot. I don't want to have `{tujuan=}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> No, please refer to the screenshot. I don't want to have {tujuan=}

To get only the value of that `tujuan` property, please change the following line of code:

```
spinnerDataList.add(item.getValue().toString());
```

to:

```
spinnerDataList.add(item.child("tujuan").getValue(String.class));
```